# How to Escape Google Chrome webkitSpeechRecognition for the word "period" to prevent "." Interpretation?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, speech-recognition, reserved-words

I am working on a simple speech recognition page using HTML and JavaScript. There are certain reserved words and phrases that are apparently undefined in the API documentation for Google Chrome's Speech Recognition implementation.

Here are a few common examples:

1. "new paragraph" - works great and not ambiguous
2. "period" - unconditionally returns the character "." even if you spell out the letters in the microphone "p e r i o d" it still outputs ".".
3. "comma" - unconditionally returns the character "," even if you spell out the letters in the microphone "c o m m a" it still outputs ",".

There may be more and I would love to get a full list them.

Does anyone know how or what to say to escape the "." to spell out the word "period"?

**Here is my test code for chrome-speech-to-text.php**

```
    <?php 
        simple_speech();
    ?>
    <?php 
    
    function simple_speech(){
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple Speech to Text</title>
    
    <?php
    $browser="";
             if(strpos(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]),strtolower("MSIE"))){?>
    <p id="info_upgrade" style="text-align:center;">Simple Speech to Text is not supported by this browser.
        Upgrade to <a href="//www.google.com/chrome">Chrome</a>
        version 25 or later.</p>
    <?php }
             else if(strpos(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]),strtolower("Presto")))
             {
                     //$browser="opera";
             }
             else if(strpos(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]),strtolower("CHROME")))
             {?>
    
    <?php 
             }
             else if(strpos(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]),strtolower("SAFARI")))
             { ?>
    <p id="info_upgrade" style="text-align:center;">Simple Speech to Text is not supported by this browser.
        Upgrade to <a href="//www.google.com/chrome">Chrome</a>
        version 25 or later.</p>
    <?php }
             else if(strpos(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]),strtolower("FIREFOX")))
             { ?>
    <p id="info_upgrade" style="text-align:center;">Simple Speech to Text is not supported by this browser.
        Upgrade to <a href="//www.google.com/chrome">Chrome</a>
        version 25 or later.</p>
    <?php }
             else 
             {
             //$browser="other";
             }
    echo $browser;
    ?>
    
    <div style="margin-bottom:50px">
        <div style="width:100%">
            <textarea name="q" id="transcript" rows="15" style="width:100% !important;"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 20px;margin-left: 10px;float:left;">
            <a id="copy_dictation" onclick="speakcopy();" style="padding: 6px 11px;background-color:#2111c4;cursor:pointer;color:#fff;margin-top:10px;border-radius:5px;"> Copy</a>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 20px;margin-left: 10px;float:left;">
            <a id="clear_dictation" onclick="speakclear()" style="padding: 6px 11px;background-color:#e5225c;cursor:pointer;color:#fff;margin-top:10px;border-radius:5px;"> Clear</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- HTML5 Speech Recognition API -->
    <script>
        startDictation()
    
        function startDictation() {
    
            var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
            console.log(recognition);
            recognition.continuous = true;
            recognition.interimResults = true;
            recognition.lang = "en";
    
            recognition.onend = function(e) {
                console.log('ended');
                var textarea = document.getElementById('transcript');
                if (textarea.value != '') {
                    textarea.value = textarea.value.trim();
                    textarea.value += ' ';
    
                }
                recognition.start();
            }
    
            recognition.onresult = function(e) {
                var textarea = document.getElementById('transcript');
                for (var i = e.resultIndex; i < e.results.length; ++i) {
                    if (e.results[i].isFinal) {
                        textarea.value += e.results[i][0].transcript;
                    }
                }
            }
    
            // start listening
            recognition.start();
        }
    
        function speakcopy() {
            var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
            recognition.stop();
            copyToClipboard(document.getElementById("transcript"));
        }
    
        function speakclear() {
            var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
            recognition.stop();
            document.getElementById("transcript").value = "";
        }
    
    
    
    
        function copyToClipboard(elem) {
    
            // create hidden text element, if it doesn't already exist
            var targetId = "_hiddenCopyText_";
            var isInput = elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
            var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
            if (isInput) {
                // can just use the original source element for the selection and copy
                target = elem;
                origSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
                origSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;
            } else {
                // must use a temporary form element for the selection and copy
                target = document.getElementById(targetId);
                if (!target) {
                    var target = document.createElement("textarea");
                    target.style.position = "absolute";
                    target.style.left = "-9999px";
                    target.style.top = "0";
                    target.id = targetId;
                    document.body.appendChild(target);
                }
                target.textContent = elem.textContent;
            }
            // select the content
            var currentFocus = document.activeElement;
            target.focus();
            target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);
    
            // copy the selection
            var succeed;
            try {
                succeed = document.execCommand("copy");
            } catch (e) {
                succeed = false;
            }
            // restore original focus
            if (currentFocus && typeof currentFocus.focus === "function") {
                currentFocus.focus();
            }
    
            if (isInput) {
                // restore prior selection
                elem.setSelectionRange(origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd);
            } else {
                // clear temporary content
                target.textContent = "";
            }
            return succeed;
        }
    
    </script>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering my own question but I have a serious deadline to meet.
Here is an example sentence to speak into the microphone.
"This was a great period in time dot"
The solution was two part:

1. Say "dot" for a period character.
2. Iterate through the alternative final results to find the word "period" and use that alternative. (returns "this was a great period in time.")

**Here is the cleaned up code with the alternative final results iteration (NOTE: the file must have a ".PHP" extension! It will not work with an HTML extension") I used the filename chrome-speech-to-text.php**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple Speech to Text</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div style="margin-bottom:50px">
      <div style="width:100%">
        <textarea name="q" id="transcript" rows="15" style="width:100% !important;"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top: 20px;margin-left: 10px;float:left;">
        <a id="copy_dictation" onclick="speakcopy();" style="padding: 6px 11px;background-color:#2111c4;cursor:pointer;color:#fff;margin-top:10px;border-radius:5px;"> Copy</a>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top: 20px;margin-left: 10px;float:left;">
        <a id="clear_dictation" onclick="speakclear()" style="padding: 6px 11px;background-color:#e5225c;cursor:pointer;color:#fff;margin-top:10px;border-radius:5px;"> Clear</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      startDictation()

      function startDictation() {

        var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
        console.log(recognition);
        recognition.continuous = true;
        recognition.interimResults = true;
        recognition.lang = "en";
        recognition.maxAlternatives = 10;

        recognition.onend = function(e) {
          //console.log('ended');
          var textarea = document.getElementById('transcript');
          if (textarea.value != '') {
            textarea.value = textarea.value.trim();
            textarea.value += ' ';

          }
          recognition.start();
        }

        recognition.onresult = function(e) {
          //console.log(e); // DO NOT UNCOMMENT ELSE ENDLESS LOOP
          //e.results[0][0].forEach(iterate);
          var textarea = document.getElementById('transcript');
          var finalText = '';
          for (var i = e.resultIndex; i < e.results.length; ++i) {
            if (e.results[i].isFinal) {
              var alternatePeriod = searchForAlternative(e.results[i], 'period');
              if (alternatePeriod != '') {
                textarea.value += alternatePeriod;
              } else {
                textarea.value += e.results[i][0].transcript;
              }
            }
          }
        }

        // start listening
        recognition.start();
      }

      function searchForAlternative(resultItem, searchString) {
        for (var i = 0; i < resultItem.length; ++i) {
          //console.log(resultItem[i].transcript);
          if (resultItem[i].transcript.includes(searchString)) {
            //console.log(resultItem[i].transcript);
            return (resultItem[i].transcript);;
          }
        }
        return ('');
      }

      function speakcopy() {
        var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
        recognition.stop();
        copyToClipboard(document.getElementById("transcript"));
      }

      function speakclear() {
        var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
        recognition.stop();
        document.getElementById("transcript").value = "";
      }

      function copyToClipboard(elem) {

        // create hidden text element, if it doesn't already exist
        var targetId = "_hiddenCopyText_";
        var isInput = elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
        var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
        if (isInput) {
          // can just use the original source element for the selection and copy
          target = elem;
          origSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
          origSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;
        } else {
          // must use a temporary form element for the selection and copy
          target = document.getElementById(targetId);
          if (!target) {
            var target = document.createElement("textarea");
            target.style.position = "absolute";
            target.style.left = "-9999px";
            target.style.top = "0";
            target.id = targetId;
            document.body.appendChild(target);
          }
          target.textContent = elem.textContent;
        }
        // select the content
        var currentFocus = document.activeElement;
        target.focus();
        target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);

        // copy the selection
        var succeed;
        try {
          succeed = document.execCommand("copy");
        } catch (e) {
          succeed = false;
        }
        // restore original focus
        if (currentFocus && typeof currentFocus.focus === "function") {
          currentFocus.focus();
        }

        if (isInput) {
          // restore prior selection
          elem.setSelectionRange(origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd);
        } else {
          // clear temporary content
          target.textContent = "";
        }
        return succeed;
      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```